# Как в PHPStorm 9 включить динамическое обновление папки

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.

Открыл проект, имею слева поле со структурой папок и файлов. Через консоль, либо другим образом (не из PHPStorm) создаю какой-нибудь файл в какой-либо папке проекта.

Далее чтобы увидеть этот новый файл в папке из PHPStorm, мне приходится либо в дереве папок мышкой свернуть и снова развернуть папку, в которой был создан новый файл, либо правой кнопкой мыши по этой папке и там выбрать пункт Synchronize ...

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать автоматическое динамическое обновление структуры проекты, чтобы не приходилось постоянно руками (мышкой) обновлять содержимое папки, в которую добавлен новый файл? Либо может как-то горячую клавишу можно повесить, чтобы нажал и структура папок и файлов в проекте обновилась?

Спасибо.

Comment: Какая ОС? У меня на линуксе синхронизации происходит далеко не моментально, но вполне автоматически. Возможно, ему нужен какой-нибудь inotify.

Comment: Win8 - у меня вообще синхронизация не происходит автоматически (даже через минуту), может какую-то настройку для этого нужно включить?

Comment: Я бы обратился в поддержку, там с большей вероятностью что-то посоветуют

Comment: и через час тоже ничего автоматически не синхронизируется, вообщем пока руками не проделаю, то что описано в первом после, новый файл не появляется в папке проекта в PHPStorm

Comment: Шторм не сканирует папки после первого открытия, для экономии ресурсов. Можно только либо заново закрыть, открыть, либо нажать синхронизация (Ctrl+Alt+Y)

Answer (score 1):

Никакой автоматической синхронизации с внешними изменениями нет (и не планируется, т.к. постоянное сканирование файловой системы требует слишком много ресурсов). Синхронизировать виртуальную файловую систему с внешними изменениями можно либо вручную (используя `Synchronize`), или переключением фокуса на другое приложение и обратно (если  '`Synchronize files on frame activation`' (Preferences | Appearance & Behavior| System settings) активна)